# filter_if to filter only factor columns that are not equal to 0

Tags: r, dplyr

As in the title, I want to drop all the rows for which any of my factor columns is equal to 0. I have found out, that `filter_if` could be probably used to do so, but I'm struggling to fully understand the syntax. Well, as I understand `.vars_predicate` argument set to `all_vars(expr)` should apply the `expr` to every selected with `.predicate` column and return an observation only if `expr` is satisfied for all of them. So when I specify it like below:

```
df %>% filter_if(~is.factor(.), all_vars(. != 0))
```

it should return the rows for which all factor variables are different than 0. However, it doesn't work and I end up with empty dataset, which is certainly not correct. Where I'm making a mistake?

My dataset looks kind of like below:

```
structure(list(group = c(918893L, 918893L, 918894L, 918895L, 
918895L, 918895L, 918895L, 918895L, 918896L, 918896L, 918896L, 
918896L, 918896L, 918896L, 918897L, 918948L, 919051L, 918974L, 
919056L, 918944L, 919068L, 919250L, 919181L, 919247L, 919072L, 
919122L, 919077L, 918935L, 918988L, 919083L), X1 = structure(c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
X3 = structure(c(1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
X4 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), X5 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), n = c(926L, 1778L, 2521L, 3727L, 
3750L, 3765L, 4668L, 4910L, 5040L, 5465L, 5586L, 5649L, 5914L, 
6419L, 6791L, 95820L, 278882L, 141727L, 288089L, 89158L, 
309150L, 633594L, 511987L, 626841L, 316258L, 405562L, 325873L, 
73109L, 166452L, 334959L)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame", 
.Names = c("group", 
"X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "n"))
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your dataset?  If I do `mtcars$fvs = factor(mtcars$vs)` and then `filter_if(mtcars, ~ is.factor(.), all_vars(. != 0))` things seem to work.

Comment: Agreed with aosmith. Extending their example to additional columns, if we use `mt = mutate(mtcars, fvs = factor(vs), fam = factor(am), not_factor_0 = 0)`, then `mt %>% filter_if(~is.factor(.), all_vars(. != 0))` seems to work just fine. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? How sure are you that the result "is certainly not correct"? What are you doing to verify?

Comment: I updated my post with sample of my dataset. I think that `NA` value may make the difference. How should I handle them in this case? By 'doesn't work' I mean that my call returns 0 rows when there are some rows without `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's quite shameing that I didn't thought of that in the first place, but simple adding `is.na` seems to work just fine:

```
df %>% filter_if(~is.factor(.), all_vars(. != 0 | is.na(.)))
```